# Is there any way to automatically add a new row into a junction table in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reference, sql-server-2014-express, junction-table

I have two tables, `tbl_Interview` and `tbl_JobSeeker` the relation between the two is many to many, the normalization rules require me to create a new table which I called `tbl_Interview_JobSeeker` with the other two tables primary keys, my question is: If the table `tbl_Interview_JobSeeker` is a junction table is there anyway when I create a new row in the `tbl_Interview` table to automatically create a new row in the junction table as well?

Comment: You could create a trigger which updates the junction table after insert on the other table.  Which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL express 2014. I would also have to create e trigger to delete correct?

Comment: No.  SQL Server has on cascade delete, so cleanup might not be too much trouble.

Comment: hmmm so just to sum it up. I need to create a trigger to add a new row to the junction table, and to delete I do it programatically correct?

Comment: You could also just two separate insert statements.  It really depends on your particular needs.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to make things more autonomus. I have another question which you may know. I will use E-mail as username, and someone suggested that the data type of the username should be `uniqueidentifier` is this assumption correct?

Comment: I would use `varchar` for the email, but include an `id` column which is unique across all users.

Comment: All my columns have ID :) so the only way that I can actually validate is the username already exists is by querying all of the database?

Comment: Yes, this is how databases work.  You could add an index on the username table to make it faster.

Comment: by index you mean store the number of let's say users in the table? what do you mean exactly by index?

Comment: Why? For which JobSeeker would the new row in tbl_Interview_JobSeeker be? All of them?

Comment: @RhysJones a new row is only added to `tbl_Interview_JobSeeker` when a new row is also added to `tbl_Interview `.
So let's say that an interview was created with user 1 and the interview ID is 2, a row should be added to `tbl_Interview_JobSeeker` with the UserID = 1 and InterviewID = 2, and this happens everytime a new row is added to the interview table

Comment: the new values will the the InterviewID which is an int and refers to the InterviewID in the tbl_Interview and also the UserID which is also an int and refers to the UserID table. Was this your question?

Comment: If an interview only has one JobSeeker then there's no need for the junction table. Is the JobSeeker primary key UserID?

Comment: I would create an `insert` stored procedure that does both inserts. That way you only have to make one call and don't have to have some messy trigger action.

Comment: @RhysJones an Interview has multiple job seekers and job seekers have multiple interviews hence the new junction table. The primary key on the Job Seekers table is UserID yes

Comment: @jkdba that's actually a pretty good idea, and create another proc to delete as well

Comment: A normal many-to-many then. In which case the INSERT to tbl_Interview doesn't include any details of the JobSeeker (UserID) so it can't create a row in the junction-table.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/bhypt8 see this. maybe it will help to understand better

Comment: @RhysJones why can't it create a new row in Junction table? In the interview table I don't have a field for the Job Seeker. please see the link in the comment above :)

Comment: I'm using the word INSERT as a SQL statement. If you want the application 'action' of creating a new row in tbl_Interview to also create a new row in tbl_Interview_JobSeeker then you can do that but you have to manage it at the application layer, which could be a stored procedure as @jkdba suggests, but it can't be a trigger on the tbl_Interview table.

Comment: @RhysJones oh ok thank you :) I think I will take the proc aproach, seems easy and it's a good aproach imo

Comment: the proc would be something like this: http://prntscr.com/bhyz9r

Comment: I don't know why but it's not recognizing the tables name or fields

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to use a stored procedure to handle creating the relationship between the JobSeeker and Interview which are independent entities and live on their own. This many-to-many relationship is very common in relational reality. Below is an example of tackling the relationship in a relational database. Though it uses the concept of Person and Course.

**Create the tables**

```
create table Person (
    PersonId int identity(1, 1)
        primary key clustered,
    FirstName varchar(128),
    LastName varchar(128))

create table Course (
    CourseId int identity(1, 1)
        primary key clustered,
    CourseName varchar(128) unique);

create table PersonCourse (
    PersonId int not null
        references Person(PersonId),
    CourseId int not null
        references Course(CourseId),
    primary key clustered (PersonId, CourseId));
go
```

**Create the stored procedures used for CRUD operations**

These are just some examples. Many of these types of procedures are more complicated to protect against incomplete, inaccurate and/or invalid data.

Additionally, it goes without saying that there are many alternatives to this approach and much debate on where these types of checks belong. Just know that this is one approach.

```
create proc dbo.CreatePerson
    @FirstName varchar(128),
    @LastName varchar(128),
    @PersonId int = null output
as begin try

    set nocount on;

    insert Person (FirstName, LastName)
        values (@FirstName, @LastName);

    set @PersonId = scope_identity();

end try
begin catch
    throw;
end catch
go

create proc dbo.CreateCourse
    @CourseName varchar(128),
    @CourseId int = null output
as begin try

    set nocount on;

    insert Course(CourseName)
        values (@CourseName);

    set @CourseId = scope_identity();

end try
begin catch
    throw;
end catch
go

create proc dbo.AddCourse
    @PersonId int,
    @CourseId int
as begin try

    set nocount on;

    if not exists (
        select * 
        from Person
        where PersonId = @PersonId)
            throw 50000, 'Person does not exist.', 1;

    if not exists (
        select *
        from Course
        where CourseId = @CourseId)
            throw 50001, 'Course does not exist.', 1;

    insert PersonCourse (PersonId, CourseId)
        values (@PersonId, @CourseId);

end try
begin catch
    throw;
end catch
go
```

**Create some sample data**

```
insert Person (FirstName, LastName)
    values
        ('Bruce', 'Wayne'),
        ('Clark', 'Kent'),
        ('Flash', 'Gordon');

insert Course (CourseName)
    values
        ('The History of Spandex'),
        ('Super Hero Physics'),
        ('Rocket Ships and the Stuff of Science Fiction');
go
```

**Add some courses**

```
exec AddCourse 1, 1; -- Bruce wants to take The History of Spandex
exec AddCourse 2, 2; -- Clark wants to take Super Hero Physics
exec AddCourse 3, 1; -- Flash wants to take The History of Spandex
exec AddCourse 3, 3; -- Flash wants to also take Rocket Ships and the Stuff of Science Fiction
```

**Query the data**

```
select
    pc.PersonId,
    p.FirstName,
    p.LastName,
    c.CourseId,
    c.CourseName
from PersonCourse pc
join Person p
    on pc.PersonId = p.PersonId
join Course c
    on pc.CourseId = c.CourseId;
```

**And the results**

```
PersonId    FirstName  LastName   CourseId    CourseName
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- -----------------------------------------------
1           Bruce      Wayne      1           The History of Spandex
2           Clark      Kent       2           Super Hero Physics
3           Flash      Gordon     1           The History of Spandex
3           Flash      Gordon     3           Rocket Ships and the Stuff of Science Fiction
```